# How to add code in tinymce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I'm trying to write a tinyMce plugin to add and also separate code from text like [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) website , actually to show code in a simple box 
how can I do that ?

Comment: are you able to implement tinyMCE

Comment: ? do you know any plugin for that ?

Comment: if you want to implement tinytext editor then there are many options for you like, ClEditor, CkEditor, tinyMCE etc                                                                                                                                          http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254007/An-Example-to-Use-HTML-Rich-Text-Editor-Cleditor

Comment: No , I'm just using TinyMCE! I don't know how to add code of post and make it separate from text

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code plugin. Just add `code` to your tinymce button list.